# Bitcoin generate Exe file using bitcoin-0.8.1 version

Tags: bitcoin

0.8.1 version and when i compile this version but successfully compiled but now i want to generate the window executable file(.exe)
from bitcoin-0.8.1 version. so latest version and older bitcoin-0.8.1 version  have big difference in new version they have depends folder and other all file from where we can get exe file for new version but in bitcoin-0.8.1 how i can generate window executable file mean exe file please help me if anyone knows about this thanks